# How to pass array from ajax to php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to pass array from ajax to php (controller).

What is wrong with second code as `var_dump($data)` of first code returns appropriate content and second returns NULL?

FIRST. GOOD.

```
function myFunction() {
    var elementy = document.getElementsByClassName('inputISBN');
    var data = elementy[0].value;

    $.ajax({
           url: "{{ path('test') }}",
           type: "POST",
           data: { "data": data }

    });   

}
```

SECOND. BAD

```
function myFunction() {
    var elementy = document.getElementsByClassName('inputISBN');
    var data = [];    
    data[elementy[0].name] = elementy[0].value;

    $.ajax({
           url: "{{ path('test') }}",
           type: "POST",
           data: { "data": data }
    });   
}
```

THIRD. UGLY

```
var elementy = document.getElementsByClassName('inputISBN');
undefined
var data = []; 
undefined
data[elementy[0].name] = elementy[0].value;
"667"
```

Third one is line by line  from the socond code written in browser console. And it's return what it should.

---

edit

and data is pulled out from here:

```
<input type="number" class="inputISBN" size="2" name="exampleName" 
                value="666" onchange="myFunction()">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When passing an array to PHP, you want to include the array indicator: `[]`. I thi8nk you need an Object: `{}`.

```
function myFunction() {
    var elementy = $('.inputISBN');
    var data = {};
    $.each(elementy, function(){
      data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
    })

    $.ajax({
           url: "{{ path('test') }}",
           type: "POST",
           data: { "data": data }
    });   
}
```

At this point, you may also want to serialize the data (as was mentioned in the other answer by @Adelphia):

`'data': JSON.stringify(data)`

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/cw77ann7/

You can call it in PHP: `print_r($_POST['data']);`

Comment: What difference would that make for PHP?

Comment: Depends... it's not clear from OPs code what he's trying to do. But that is how you pass data to be part of an array. And that's what he asked.

Comment: @Twisty `elementy[0].name` are text type data allways, and `elementy[0].value`  are number. Your hint with array indicator does not work. Still NULL.

Comment: Added an update/edit. Let me know if this is more of what you're looking to do.

Comment: @Twisty I have zero experience with JavaScript/Ajax so if I should paste your code with no change then it's still return NULL.

Comment: @Twisty if `data` is an array in Javascript, it will be an array in PHP when it's sent via AJAX - you don't need the add `[]` to make that happen

Comment: @scrowler ok, i give up, i though i can just use little JavaScript in my App without learning JavaScript.

Comment: It's hard to say. Too abstract of a question. You never provided more information so I can't say if this code will work as is.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something here. Where is this array of data? There is only 1 `<input>`?

Comment: @Twisty input tag is in the loop https://jsfiddle.net/f3oLsu9m/2/ (Thats to previous question)

Answer (score 1):

You want to pass your `data` variable to PHP, which is an array, right? Why not `data = JSON.stringify(data);` and then on PHP's side, `$data = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);`

```
function myFunction() {
    var elementy = document.getElementsByClassName('inputISBN');
    i = elementy.length;
    data = [];
    while(i--) data[elementy[i].name] = elementy[i].value;
    data = JSON.stringify(data);

    $.ajax({
           url: "{{ path('test') }}",
           type: "POST",
           data: { "data": data }

    });   

}
```

Comment: should I just paste your line`data = JSON.stringify(data);` after line `data[elementy[0].name] = elementy[0].value;` (from my SECOND code) ? If yes then var_dump return `array (size=1)
  0 => string '[]' (length=2)` instead of something like`['name']=>'667'`

Comment: @Sruj make a jsfiddle and let me see what you're actually doing, I'll fix it up for you.

Comment: @AdeIphia sorry for waisting your time, i don't belive it might help you https://jsfiddle.net/f3oLsu9m/1/ .

Comment: @Sruj - There is no array in your fiddle. I still don't understand what you're doing. I'd like to help, I just don't get it.

Comment: @AdeIphia its test version to simplify my real version. I can do it again.

Comment: There is still no array there @Sruj

Comment: @AdeIphia I take back above. I dont get you by saying 'no array'. `var data = []` is an array. F.e. `data['one']=>'1', data['two']=>'2'`,

Comment: @Adelphia - https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/cw77ann7/ he did not draw out the loop any